# Finding a string inside another string [php] -- matching all for some reason?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a form supplied UTC time and form supplied event name string with an array read in from a file. The problem is that it seems to always match even when it shouldn't. The format of the file will always be constant, so I know I'll be looking for a value within double quotes, so after failing to get results with strpos(), I tried preg_match...and now match everything. Code and example output follow ($utc and $event_name)are already set and correct when we get here):

```
$match1 = "/\"{$utc}\"/";
       $match2 = "/\"{$event_name}\"/";
       print "Match Values: $match1, $match2<p>";

foreach($line_array as $key => $value) {
   print "Value = $value<p>";

   if ((preg_match($match1,$value) == 1) and (preg_match($match2,$value) == 1))
   {
       print "Case 1 - False<p>";
   } else {
      print "Contains targets: $value<p>";
      //code to act on hit will go here
   }
}
```

And here's what comes back:

```
Match Values: /"1371033000000"/, /"Another test - MkII "/

Value = { "date": "1357999200000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Plant and Animal Genome     Conference, San Diego, CA", "description": "NCGAS to present at Plant and Animal Genome   Conference, San Diego, CA", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" }

Contains targets: { "date": "1357999200000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Plant and Animal Genome Conference, San Diego, CA", "description": "NCGAS to present at Plant and  Animal Genome Conference, San Diego, CA", "url": "http://www.event1.com/" }

Value = { "date": "1357693200000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Testing Addition",  "description": "This is a fake event.", "url": "http://pti.iu.edu" }

Contains targets: { "date": "1357693200000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Testing Addition", "description": "This is a fake event.", "url": "http://pti.iu.edu" }

Value = { "date": "1371033000000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Another test - MkII", "description": "This is a fake event.", "url": "http://pti.iu.edu" }

Contains targets: { "date": "1371033000000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Another test - MkII", "description": "This is a fake event.", "url": "http://pti.iu.edu" }
```

I should only be matching the last one, but they all match. I've been playing with the regex and can't seem to find the right magic.

Comment: If your files are actually JSON strings, why don't you simply decode them?

Comment: I haven't tried regex with PHP yet (soon though) but I recommend being careful with what you put in your regex definitions. Some of the characters you used could be mistaken in the regex. Check [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for details on building your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified it and got what I was after:

```
foreach($line_array as $key => $value) {
   print "Value = $value<p>";
   if (preg_match("/$utc/",$value) and preg_match("/$event_time/",$value))
   {
       print "Contains targets: $value<p>";
   } else {
       print "Case 1 - False<p>";
      //code to act on hit will go here
   }
}
```

But answer 2 got me in the right direction. Thanks, Ian!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything weird inside a double-quoted string, just drop your variable in as is...

```
$match1 = "/$utc/";
$match2 = "/$event_name/";
```

I suspect your regexes are looking for zero-length strings.

Also, this line doesn't need so many parentheses...

```
if (preg_match($match1,$value) == 1 and preg_match($match2,$value) == 1) {
    [...]
}
```